# How to filter excel column data based on column values delimited by "-" character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using excel sheet and the data is in the format as shown below.

```
1416061-11
1416061-1
1416061-3
1416806-8
1416806-9
1416806-1
1416806-10
1416809-1
1416806-11
1416806-3
1416806-5
```

How can i filter only those particular rows that ends with "-1" only ?

So from the example above, only below mention records should be displayed.

```
1416061-1
1416806-1
1416809-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in function "Ends- with" from the filter should work

[image]

---

Then...

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for easy and accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

This array formula (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`) should do the trick:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF(RIGHT($A$1:$A$11,2)="-1",ROW($A$1:$A$11)),ROW(A1)))),"")
```

[image]